# Usar variáveis PHP no corpo do e-mail HTML do phpMailer

Tags: php, envio-de-email, phpmailer

Pessoal preciso enviar a seguinte mensagem por e-mail usando phpMailer: "Olá, [NOME]! Há um novo protocolo referente ao documento nº [xxx]".

consegui configurar tudo certinho, no entanto o local destinados ao nome e o número permanecem em branco. Consegui resgatar os dois e colocar em variáveis, mais seus valores não são carregados na mensagem. Segue um trecho do código:

```
<tr>
    <p> Olá, <?php echo $nome ?>! </p>
</tr>
<tr>
    <p>
        Há um novo protocolo referente ao documento nº <?php echo $controle ?>.
    </p>
</tr>
```

A variável `$nome` guarda o nome do usuário que receberá o e-mail e $controle o número de controle do documento.

---

Essa é a classe que contem a função de envio usando o phpMailer:

```
 class emailDAO {

    function avisoProcesso($nome, $email, $controle){

        $mensagem = "
                <table width='800' hidden='300' xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/html\"     border='no'>
                    <tr>
                        <img src='http://goo.gl/evcwLn'>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor='#E0E6F8' height='150'>
                        <p>
                            <b>
                                <h1>                                      
                                    Olá, <?php echo $nome ?>!
                                </h1>
                            </b>
                        </p>
                        <p>                              
                            Há um novo protocolo referente ao documento nº <?php echo $controle ?>.
                        </p>
                    </tr>                        
                </table>";

    $mail = new PHPMailer(); //
    // Define o método de envio
    $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
    // Define que a mensagem poderá ter formatação HTML
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    // Define que a codificação do conteúdo da mensagem será utf-8
    $mail->CharSet    = "utf-8";
    // Define que os emails enviadas utilizarão SMTP Seguro tls
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    // Define que o Host que enviará a mensagem é o Gmail
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
    //Define a porta utilizada pelo Gmail para o envio autenticado
    $mail->Port       = "587";
    // Deine que a mensagem utiliza método de envio autenticado
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = "true";
    // Define o usuário do gmail autenticado responsável pelo envio
    $mail->Username   = "meu.email@gmail.com";
    // Define a senha deste usuário citado acima
    $mail->Password   = "senha";
    // Defina o email e o nome que aparecerá como remetente no cabeçalho
    $mail->From       = "meu.email@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName   = "Notificação";
    // Define o destinatário que receberá a mensagem
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    //Define o email que receberá resposta desta mensagem, quando o destinatário responder.
    $mail->AddReplyTo("meu.email@gmail.com", $mail->FromName);
    // Assunto da mensagem
    $mail->Subject    = "DTEC - Nova Solicitação";

    // Toda a estrutura HTML e corpo da mensagem do e-mail.
    $mail->Body       = $mensagem;

    // Controle de erro ou sucesso no envio
    if (!$mail->Send()){?>
        <script>
            alert("Houve um erro no envio do e-mail de cadastro, caso deseje pode fazer manualmente.");
        </script>
    <?php }else{ ?>
        <script>
            alert("Um e-mail foi enviado avisando sobre a criação deste protocolo.");
        </script>
    <?php }
}
```

Tudo funciona perfeitamente, senão por um espaço em branco onde desejo que apareçam o nome do usuário e o nº de controle do documento.

A função é chamada no fim do cadastramento enviando os três parâmetros ($nome, $email e $controle); fiz a verificação e as três variáveis recebem o conteúdo corretamente. No entanto não exibe no corpo do e-amil.

Comment: Onde foi definida `$nome`?

Comment: Ponha seu código por inteiro. Ajudará a visualizar melhor o problema

Comment: No código acima basta  trocar `Olá, <?php echo $nome ?>!` por `Olá, ".$nome."!` e `documento nº <?php echo $controle ?>.` por `documento nº ".$controle."` - O problema é que você já está tentando fazer coisa mais complexa sem ter aprendido o básico sobre variáveis e strings. Sugeriria ler com calma o manual do PHP e fazer alguns exercícios sem pular etapas, para um melhor aproveitamento da linguagem. Sobre o conhecimento necessário para resolver essa questão, aqui é um bom começo: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 2):

Você pode também simplificar este processo utilizando o [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php).

Em vez de abrir e fechar tags php no seu html você pode criar um macro e efetuar a substituição.

### Exemplo:

```
$body = '<tr>
    <p> Olá, [NOME]! </p>
</tr>
<tr>
    <p>
        Há um novo protocolo referente ao documento nº [CONTROLE].
    </p>
</tr>';

// Dados
$nome = 'Gabriel Rodrigues';
$controle = 'Dados do Controle';
// Substituindo Macros pelos valores.
$body = str_replace('[NOME]', $nome, $body);
$body = str_replace('[CONTROLE]', $controle, $body);
echo $body;
```

Facilita bastante se você precisa substituir mais de um campo com o mesmo valor.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o ob_start() para isso

```
ob_start();
// seu codigo php aqui
$mensagem = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$mail = new PHPMaier(); //  
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "meu.email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "senha";
$mail->From = "meu.email@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Notificação";
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->AddReplyTo("meu.email@gmail.com", $mail->FromName);
$mail->Subject = "DTEC - Nova Solicitação";
$mail->Body = $mensagem;

if (!$mail->Send()){ ?>
....
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php